# На запрос к vk api приходит пустой ответ

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

До падения сервера хостинга было все нормально. После починки стали приходить пустые ответы. В чем может быть проблема ? Вот пример запроса.

```
function getName($u_id) {
$user_id = $u_id;
$request_params = array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'fields' => 'first_name',
    'lang' => 'ru',
    'v' => '5.52'
);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'. $get_params));
return $result;
```

Comment: проблема не воспроизводится.... так что тут только гадать на кофейной гуще можно.........разве что у вас также в коде не закрыта фигурная скобка у функции как в примере....

Comment: Кстати, нам обещают, что с апреля такое работать не будет из-за обязательности ключа доступа при использовании открытых методов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В работе функции я проблем не заметил, если не считать что у вас отсуствует закрывающая кавычка  `}`,   а так, норм работает:

```
<?php 
function getName($u_id) {
$user_id = $u_id;
$request_params = array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'fields' => 'first_name',
    'lang' => 'ru',
    'v' => '5.52'
);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'. $get_params));
return $result;
}

print_r(getName('252494459'));
?>
```